# Sax parsing a large file from S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, streaming, large-files, saxparser

I have a very large xml file on s3 (50gb). I would like to stream this file to a sax xml parser for further processing using ruby. How would I do that in an environment where I cannon download the whole file locally, but only stream it over tcp from s3?

I'm thinking about using https://github.com/ohler55/ox for the parsing it self, and https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby for accessing the file on S3. I'm just unsure how connect the pieces using a streaming approach?

Comment: https://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most easiest way is to use `mc`. `mc` implements are `cat` command which can used in a simpler way.

For example as shown below. Here `cat` streams your object and pipe the output of `cat` to your XML parser which reads from stdinput.

```
$ mc cat s3.amazonaws.com/<yourbucket>/<yourobject> | <your_xml_parser>
```

This way you can avoid downloading the file locally.

Additionally `mc` provides more tools to work with Amazon S3 compatible cloud storage and filesystems. It has features like resumable uploads, progress bar, parallel copy. `mc` is written in Golang and released under Apache license v2. `mc` is supported on OS X, Linux and Windows.